# How to remove saved smb or sftp username and password in thunar kali linux?

Tags: ssh, kali-linux, password, sftp, thunar

I have logged in to a user and logged out, after that, I want to connect to the same host again but on different user. And i can not do that because thunar automatically logged me into the old user.

I have searched on google but I still can not do that in my laptop.
How do i solve this one?

Answer (score -1):

In terminal type:

```
sudo smbpasswd -x username
```

Additionally check do you have seahorse installed. It stores passwords.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to delete his Samba account, just login as a different user.

Comment: How about sftp?

Comment: Did OP use seahorse?